# Changing Application name showing in Google Two factor Authentication app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

After scanning the barcode we will get a key in our google authenticator app and also it's showing the project name belong that secret key, How can we change that name.

eg: In my case, I have a web service project named as Identity.API

After scanning the QR code my google authenticator app showing
"Identity.API(pms@xtrastaff.com)" belonging with a secret key.

I need to change the project name to "XPMS(pms@xtrastaff.com)"

How can make it possible?

Comment: change the client name in clients table in identity database

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer

you can refer this page

https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/Key-Uri-Format

Just change the "Issuer" parameter when Generate QrCodeUri.The corresponding "issuer" parameter is showing in the google authenticator (application name).

Answer (score 0):

Change the client id and client name in clients table in identity database. You have to change in client id in your front end application also.